# can I make Passport.js add new field to new register accounts?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

i have this code:
i want to have another fields with the user like their phone number, but I don't know how I can add them

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
    //// here i want to add another property
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

and my registering is this:

```
User.register({ username: req.body.username }, req.body.password, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/register");
        } else {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
                res.redirect("/");
            });
        }
    });
```

I don't know where to add the new field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there! I would recommend to add the field within your schema.

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
    phoneNumber: String,
});
```

Then on your register call you will pass the data into the `User.register` method.

```js
const user = {
  username: req.body.username,
  phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
}

User.register(new User(user), req.body.password, function (err) {
// your callback logic
```

Comment: thanks, do you know how to choose what passpoer save in cookie?

Comment: If it helped, could you accept this answer as correct? After calling deserializeUser it should add the user data to `req.user`

Comment: Try just passing the user object. `User.register(user`

Comment: Is `User.register` inside of a route?